# resizing all the images in a file folder

Tags: c#, image-resizing

I am trying to resize all the images that are found in the same file folder to the same size. Here is the code I have but it is not working. A little help please (Ignore "CombineImages(files);" that is another method of the program that is working just fine)

```
    private void cmdCombine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Change the path to location where your images are stored.
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Elder Zollinger\Desktop\Images");
        if (directory != null)
        {
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
            ResizeImages(files);
            CombineImages(files);
        }

    private void ResizeImages(FileInfo[] files)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
            var newImage = ScaleImage(img, 200, 400);
        }   
    public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
        var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
        var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

        var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
        var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

        var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        return newImage;
    }
```

Comment: "Not working" means what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the resized image. Try this:

```
private void ResizeImages(FileInfo[] files)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
        var newImage = ScaleImage(img, 200, 400);

        img.Dispose();

        newImage.Save(file.FullName);
    }   
}
```

You will need to dispose the original image before you can overwrite it.